# Python regex to match and remove a specific pattern

Tags: python

I have a file with the following grammar:

```
<whitespace_sequence><string><whitespace_sequence><--More--><whitespace_sequence><string_sequence><newline>
```

Using Python (2.4), I would like to remove the sequence:

```
 "<whitespace_sequence><--More--><whitespace_sequence>" from the above grammar.
```

I am  using the following regex pattern:

```
x = re.compile("(\s+)("--More--")(\s+)")
```

but it's not matching the sequence that I need to remove.

Comment: Sample strings are way more helpful than makeshift grammars.

Comment: Is that really the code you ran? It would throw a NameError exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem with your regex is the double quotes.  Without them, it works fine:

```
>>> sample = '   string    --More--    anotherstring    \n'
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'(\s+)(--More--)(\s+)', sample).groups()
('    ', '--More--', '    ')
```

FWIW, here is a great resource for developing a regex directly from a sample string: 
http://txt2re.com/

Another good resource to learn more about regular expressions is: http://www.regular-expressions.info/